# What does it mean that backpropagation will happen into labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I received an warning today, it said

> softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating:
>
> Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow
>   into the labels input on backprop by default.

and I then checked `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2` as it suggested, and found something below

> Backpropagation will happen into both logits and labels. To disallow backpropagation into labels, pass label tensors through a stop_gradients before feeding it to this function.

I don't quite understand what it means that backpropagation will happen into labels, aren't the labels set to be constants?

Comment: check out this link, someone asked a similar question. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327348/how-is-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits-different-from-softmax-cross-entropy-wi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check out the following link, someone asked a similar question and got a nice answer to it.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327348/how-is-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits-different-from-softmax-cross-entropy-wi